# I'm adding a free w3layout templates and javascript runs twice in rails 4.2 app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, turbolinks

I'm adding a free w3layout template [Link to template](https://w3layouts.com/scrutiny-a-education-category-responsive-web-template/) to my new rails 4.2 app and when I put all files in their places it seems that the javascript event runs twice. It is visible when you reload the page (F5).

I think the reason why - is this code below and also turbolinks. But without it the event runs once and immediately to all parts of template. The question is - How can I manage these .js files to only run once, but smoothly. I'm not very good at javascript.

```
<!--animate-->
    <script>
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
<!--//end-animate-->
```

All js files I put in `app/assets/javascript`

Here's the [link](https://github.com/tjai89/helen-commercial) to full github project. And this is [application.html.erb](https://github.com/tjai89/helen-commercial/blob/master/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb) where I think all the problems are. App runs locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The problem was not in the

`<!--animate-->
    <script>
        new WOW().init();
    </script>
<!--//end-animate-->`

The reason was in this code

```
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

It was at the end of the template so I don't seen it at once.